# Modal page and button click

Tags: usability, forms, login

I have a modal page with login button. Clicking on the button verifies the username or password. And if incorrect, error messages will be shown while still being inside the modal. But I can not find a way to do this.
Please help me.

Comment: Is this an implementation question or UX question?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a few possible answers on this page -
[Most Common Log-in Problems and Solutions](https://uxplanet.org/most-common-log-in-problems-and-solutions-163a6209c0eb)

This is a common question. There must already be a few questions related to this.

[image]

Related question:
[What is best practice for designing form error messages?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/26173/what-is-best-practice-for-designing-form-error-messages)